# /sys/class filesystem on Linux

Tags: linux, sysfs

On Linux (Ubuntu 11.10 on a ARM processor in my case) I was looking for a way to measure CPU temperature. I found out that a

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

did the trick. Now I wonder: what is the /sys/class filesystem meant for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/sys is an implimentation of the sysfs (system file system) which is a virtual file system (it doesn't exist on disk)  various system internals can be read here, in a similar way `/proc` and the procfs shows process information. /sys/class shows information that relate to a class of device/attribute.

You can read an overview in this [linux.org article](https://www.linux.org/threads/sysfs-and-configfs.9353/).

> [Link updated from [@John P](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105858/john-p)'s comment below. 21 Oct 2017]

Comment: That link isn't working correctly. I see a basic explanation of `/sys` [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/sysfs-and-configfs.9353/), but Google has started selectively ignoring double quotes, so I'm having trouble finding more relevant results.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that these filesystems are virtual. They're not stored at disk permanently. So /sys will be empty if you look at it from another OS you booted.